# Way to get User Feedback for iPhone app?

Tags: ios, feedback, review

I'm looking for some services where users are pushed to try my iPhone app and give back feedback or reviews?

I would pay also.
Do you know such kind of services or websites?

Thanks
PS: I know Apperang and AppRebates already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is such service http://testflightapp.com/ you can try !!!

Comment: Or you can give it to me and I will test it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try test fight app ;)

Comment: Testflight's feedback system is annoying because it only sends one feedback message per session.

Answer (score 13):

Integrate http://instabug.com it's a very lightweight SDK that takes only 60 seconds to integrate & provides a lot of power to you. Users just shake the device to get the feedback form & send a message along with a screenshot of the app at that moment that they can annotate by drawing on.

App developers are notified instantly to login to their dashboard to check all of the feedback sent along with all of the important info about the device at that moment. Info such as ( Carrier - Memory - Storage - iOS version - console log ) & much more.

It's also a free service, I think it's worth a try.

---

For full disclosure, I work on the Instabug front end.

Comment: We are using Instabug since days now and it is so far the best solution!

Comment: Discover yesterday to a meeting IOS, it's seems to be a very comfortable solution.

Comment: How would the user know that he/she should shake the device to leave feedback? I assume that it has to be mentioned as a feature somewhere in the application?

Comment: Instabug SDK comes with a lot of customisation, it provides a first timer alert than lets users know if there is any problem they should shake the device or any other gesture it comes with 3 out of the box gestures. for more info you can go to the SDK Integration page http://instabug.com/sdk_integration

Comment: You should have disclosed your relationship with instabug. This is not cool.

Comment: I thought I did, I have it in my bio
but anyways my bad

Comment: Instabug looks very promising. I've made an edit to the answer to add in disclosure of the author's role developing Instabug's front end. This isn't supposed to reflect in any way on the quality of the answer (+1), but I think it's worth users knowing this.

Comment: @Benjohn thanks a lot I've merged your edits, and I hope you are enjoying the service.

You can send me your feedback anytime on zsherif@instabug.com I'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 10):

There are some tools that are exactly what you are looking at:

- [Instabug](http://instabug.com)
- BARK
- BlitFeedback (http://www.blitfeedback.com)
- BugClipper (http://www.bugclipper.com)

That's all I know of at the moment.

Comment: Are any of these services 64-bit ready? TestFlight has deprecated its feedback form and I just tried BlitFeedback but discovered it's not 64-bit compatible.

Comment: @JustinW Yes, Instabug is. It fully supports 64-bit.

Comment: I've already downloaded and incorporated Instabug. It works beautifully! It's even fully integrated with my BitBucket issue tracker. Great suggestion!

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried [Helpshift](https://www.helpshift.com/) ?
It looks like it has all the features that you need.

For your app's users, giving feedback is as easy as starting a new conversation with you, the app developer. The SDK can be integrated in 4 easy steps listed [in this guide](https://developers.helpshift.com/ios/getting-started/)

There are many other features such app review pop-ups, FAQ knowledge bases, rich issue management dashboard too.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried http://www.crittercism.com?  I use them for getting feedback on my apps, they are awesome!

Comment: except they aren't awesome. I had to switch from crittercism to crashlytics because their service for feed back and crashes had to many issues. Once reported they took their time fixing it.

Comment: Do crittercism and crashlytics both offer feedback forms for users or are they purely crash reporting? Also, are they 64-bit compatible?

Comment: Crashlytics doesn't provide user feedback forms.  It's crash reporting only.

Answer (score 2):

UserVoice https://www.uservoice.com/ios/ is an other service that collects feedback from users.

Answer (score 1):

Try [www.unopoll.com](http://www.unopoll.com). It's a new service for asking your users questions and seeing the answers with graphs and such. They are still on beta, but it works fine for me.

Comment: Not able to get my custom question/answer created. just show me the default question alert. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Try http://userecho.com/userecho-for-ios/
Smart way to collect and manage feedback for your iPhone and iPad applications.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link of how you can do it with the Helpshift SDK: 
https://developers.helpshift.com/ios/reviews-and-feedback/

A lot of top grossing apps use Helpshift - including: Flipboard, SuperCell's Boom Beach Game to name a few.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [www.glazum.com](https://www.glazum.com) for asking any questions in app and get instant responses.

Key features of Glazum are:

- Ability to bind questions to markers in your code at runtime. Thus
  you can ask any question almost at any time without resubmitting
  application.
- Great range of answer types you can choose.  It might be free short/long text answer, single/multiple selection (it's also possible that users comment their choices).
- There are a lot of different conditions to show questions (country, user identifiers, app version, iOS version, launches, device type and other)
- Glazum SDK is easy to use and integration is really simple
- Questions are saved locally, and thus can be shown even without internet connection. Of course If user answers a question without internet connection, the answer will be saved and send to Glazum backend later.
- There is easy-to-use dashboard, where you can manage questions and responses.
- Ability to schedule questions for specific period.
- Ability use custom variables in your code and lately show questions based on these variables values. This is very useful especially in case of a/b tests.

An example of Glazum SDK usage you can find here https://github.com/glazum/glazum-ios-example

Answer (score 0):

There is an control called [Tattle-UI](https://github.com/npctech/Tattle-UI-iOS) specially for Beta-tester during development phase. It's an basic control using Screenshot with marking and audio feedback, finally we can share it with our developers by mail. But it wouldn't be integrate with app which is on App store. They may reject with this type of feature.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the tools are already mentioned here.
Would like to add -

1- HockeyApp (http://hockeyapp.net/features/feedback/)

2- Apptentative

3- Helpshift

Updating details about BugClipper (http://bugclipper.com) 
Along with screenshot, annotations - BugClipper let's your beta testers/users report issues with screen recordings & voice.

Apps with BugClipper are approved on the app store to, so you can get feedback videos from your end users too.

(p.s. - I am the founder at BugClipper)

Answer (score 0):

Options listed so far usually require a SDK to be integrated into your app, most are costly (free ones often due to beta) and often provide fancy features like drawing on screenshots.

If you just need a simple feedback form, there is a service called [AppyForm](http://www.appyform.com) that is simply a hosted HTML custom form you can display in your app.

p.s. I built it, because I needed a service exactly like that and I can’t find one.