# iOS api to get user feedback

Tags: ios, api

I would like to know if there are any API's for iOS , using which the app feedback given by customer can be sent to the API server and from there can be sent to me via email.

Comment: have you tried testflightapp.com?

Comment: no, but I believe that's for beta testing.

Comment: so you need that in your regular app? the why not just letting users send an email with `MFMailComposeViewController`?

Comment: https://github.com/wongzigii/Butterfly This open source project will do your favour.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for this kind of API. I have found a few so far.

http://www.apptentive.com/

I *think* zendesk (https://www.zendesk.com/) has an API (not sure without signing up).

http://freshdesk.com/ has some kind of beta program, I think.

UPDATE: Here's another list on SO: [Way to get User Feedback for iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730363/way-to-get-user-feedback-for-iphone-app)