# iOS Simple In-App User Feedback Form

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-feedback

I want a very simple user feedback form in my iOS app.  I am not interested in all the fancy user feedback and support services that are on the market (See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730363/way-to-get-user-feedback-for-iphone-app)).  I'd rather just have a single form in my app like many apps on the market.  How do these apps transmit the information?  Having the app send an e-mail would be sufficient, but I don't think that can be done without using `MFMailComposeViewController`.

Below are three examples of the type of form I'm interested in from Quizlet, Google Maps, and Facebook (in that order).  How are these guys doing it?  Are they all using their custom servers?  Are there no services out there that would support this for free?

[image: Quizlet Feedback Form]

[image: Google Maps Feedback Form]

[image: Facebook Feedback Form]

Comment: Yes, they all use their custom servers. You could do it with any web hosting plan (you know, those that cost under $100 a year).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions

How are these guys doing it?

***they are using their custom API endpoints to actually submit the forms***

Are they all using their custom servers?

***yes***

Are there no services out there that would support this for free?

***you can build a very simple backend service using Parse.com. They have a drop in iOS SDK which can be used to communicate to the backend. They are also free till 1 million api requests/month***

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I just spent a few hours setting it up for myself using Parse!